# How to suppress ^C from being printed when stopping Ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I have a long running Ruby script. What is a good way to suppress ^C from being printed when the user hits CTRL-C?

```
trap 'SIGINT' do
  puts "SIGINT received. Exiting."
  exit
end

loop do
  ...
end
```

I found that puts `"\b\bSIGINT..."` works, but that feels like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent this by setting [`IO#echo=`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.2/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-echo-3D) to `false`:

```
require 'io/console'

STDIN.echo = false
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not "Ruby" printing the `^C`, it's just regular keyboard input from the terminal. If you type `asd` then that will *also* show in your terminal. This is because in terminals, all "special" keys (ctrl+key, alt+key, F1, etc.) are not really all that "special" since they're really just a character (or several characters) being sent.

You can see this for yourself by running your script and pressing some keys like `F1` (shows as `^[OP` on my system), backspace (`^H` or `^?`), etc.

It's a legacy from 1960s teletypes, where all data was transmitted over a single serial text connection.

There are some ways to fix this:

- As tadman already mentioned, you can use the `\r` character which puts the cursor at the start of the line. It doesn't actually "erase" anything, but can overwrite the `^C` with something else. Note that the `^C` will *not* be printed on a new line, so this may not work in all cases. Your `puts "\b\bSIGINT"` is probably a better solution for this!
- A second way is to use the `stty` command to prevent echoing input:

  ```
  trap 'SIGINT' do
    puts "SIGINT received. Exiting."
    exit
  end

  # Don't echo input characters
  `stty -echo`
  loop do
    sleep 1
  end
  ```

  Some systems (such as Linux) also support the `ctlecho` option, which only prevents echoing of control characters (such as `^C`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stomp over some output:

```
puts "\rSIGINT"
```

The `\r` character moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line.

Comment: This isn't really that different from using `\b\bSIGINT`, except that it doesn't move the cursor two places to the left, but to the start of the line (which may not always work if the script was outputting something when `^C` was pressed).

Comment: It's a different approach that's not always going to work, but in most cases is adequate.